# How to create a rounded corner background box using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to create a rounded corner background box using CSS?

Comment: For the background to your whole site? There are a multitude of round-corner-css tutorials available online, have you read any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this css:

```
.box_round {
     -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1+ */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4 */
          border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
}
```

And then simply use the class in your HTML like this

```
<div class="box_round" style="background-color:red">This is a test</div>
```

I added the background-color:red - just for test puporposes so that you can see the rounded corenrs.

HTH

Comment: Hi Pavel Nikolov its not working with IE8. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You cannot! Only IE 9 will support CSS3. The previous versions have no support for roudend corenrs!

Answer (score 2):

This is only supported in [CSS 3](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CSS3 PIE project. It may help you with the problems related to CSS3 on old IE versions.